# $\widehat{\sigma^{n-1}}(x) = c(n)|x|^{(2-n)/2} J_{(n-2)/2}(2\pi|x|)$ where $\sigma^{n-1}$ is the surface measure on $S^{n-1}$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4458622/lim-delta-to-0-delta-1-int-phi-dln-vert-b0-1-delta-setminus-b), we have shown that $\sigma^{n-1}$ is the weak limit of the measures $\delta^{-1} \mathcal L^n\vert_{B(0, 1+\delta)\setminus B(0,1)}$ as $\delta\to 0$.

---

For a radial function $f\in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$, i.e., $f(x) = \psi(|x|)$ for some $\psi:[0,\infty)\to \Bbb C$, Mattila proves the following expression for the Fourier transform of $f$:
$$\widehat f(x) = c(n)|x|^{-(n-2)/2} \int_0^\infty \psi(s)J_{(n-2)/2}(2\pi|x|s) s^{n/2}\, ds \tag{3.33}$$
where $J_m$'s are Bessel functions for $m > -1/2$.

---

> Applying the formula $(3.33)$ to the characteristic function of the annulus $B(0,1+\delta)\setminus B(0,1)$ and letting $\delta\to 0$, we get $$\widehat{\sigma^{n-1}}(x) = c(n)|x|^{(2-n)/2} J_{(n-2)/2}(2\pi|x|) \tag{3.41}$$

Applying the formula $(3.33)$ to the characteristic function of the annulus $B(0,1+\delta)\setminus B(0,1)$, and observing that
$$\chi_{B(0,1+\delta) \setminus B(0,1)}(x) = \chi_{\{s>0: 1 < s\le 1+\delta\}}(|x|) \tag{1}$$
we get
$$\widehat{\chi_{B(0,1+\delta) \setminus B(0,1)}}(x) = c(n)|x|^{-(n-2)/2} \int_1^{1+\delta} J_{(n-2)/2}(2\pi|x|s) s^{n/2}\, ds \tag{2}$$
Dividing both sides by $\delta$, we have
$$\frac{\widehat{\chi_{B(0,1+\delta) \setminus B(0,1)}}(x)}{\delta} = \frac{c(n)|x|^{-(n-2)/2} \int_1^{1+\delta} J_{(n-2)/2}(2\pi|x|s) s^{n/2}\, ds}{\delta} \tag{3}$$
Certainly, $$\frac{c(n)|x|^{-(n-2)/2} \int_1^{1+\delta} J_{(n-2)/2}(2\pi|x|s) s^{n/2}\, ds}{\delta} \xrightarrow{\delta\to 0} c(n)|x|^{-(n-2)/2}J_{(n-2)/2}(2\pi|x|)$$
However, to get $(3.41)$, we may have to show $$\lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{\widehat{\chi_{B(0,1+\delta) \setminus B(0,1)}}(x)}{\delta} = \widehat{\sigma^{n-1}}(x)$$
How can we do that? Thank you!

Comment: I prove that to you in a [previous posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4458629/121671) to a question of yours.

Comment: I think you are missing a factor $\delta^{-1}$. [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4458622/121671) that $\frac{1}{\delta}\int^{1+\delta}_1 h(s)\,ds\xrightarrow{\delta\rightarrow0}h(1)$ for $h$ continuous (or if $1$ is a Lebesgue point of $h$ more generally).

Comment: Thanks! Please see my edit, I have divided by $\delta$ now. @OliverDíaz

Comment: The definition of $\hat{\sigma}$ is defined as a weak limit in the fashion of one of your previous [postings](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4458622/121671)

Comment: @OliverDíaz Please see \begin{align*}\lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{\widehat{\chi_{B(0,1+\delta) \setminus B(0,1)}}(x)}{\delta} &= \lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{1}{\delta} \int \chi_{B(0,1+\delta) \setminus B(0,1)}(z) e^{-2\pi ix\cdot z}\, dz\\ &= \lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{1}{\delta} \int e^{-2\pi ix\cdot z}\, d\mathcal L^n\vert_{B(0, 1+\delta)\setminus B(0,1)}(z)\\ &{\color{red}{\stackrel{?}{=}}} \int e^{-2\pi ix\cdot \mathbf{u}}\, d\sigma^{n-1}(\mathbf{u}) \\&=\widehat{\sigma^{n-1}}(x)
\end{align*}
How do you justify ${\color{red}{\stackrel{?}{=}}}$ Is $e^{-2\pi i x\cdot z} \in C_0(\Bbb R^n)$?

Comment: Notice that the result is local, you can modify the function smoothly outside a small shell around the unit sphere.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the intuition. So, $h_1(z) := e^{-2\pi ix\cdot z}$ itself does not have compact support, but we can find modify it, say outside $B(0,2)$, to get a function, say $h_2$, of **compact support**, so that $$\int h_1(z) d\mathcal L^n\vert_{B(0, 1+\delta)\setminus B(0,1)}(z) = \int h_2(z) d\mathcal L^n\vert_{B(0, 1+\delta)\setminus B(0,1)}(z)$$
for all $\delta < 1$, right? Could you, if possible, help me with finding one such function $h_2$?

Comment: Exactly, notice that the limiting process only sees what is in the shell $1\leq |x|<1+\delta$, so, by multiplying by a radial mollifier supported in the shell, say $1/2\leq |x|<2$ that take value $1$ on $\frac34<|x|<\frac32$ you get what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136732/discussion-between-oliver-diaz-and-connected-subgroup).

Comment: @OliverDíaz [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483759/lim-r-to-infty-int-cos2rz-t-d-pi-muz-frac12-for-all-t-i) question may interest you!