# $\lim_{r\to\infty} \int \cos^2(rz + t)\, d\pi_{\#}\mu(z) = \frac12$ for all $t\in \Bbb R$

Tags: limits, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, fourier-analysis

This question stems from the identity listed as Equation $(6.6)$ in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.11414.pdf) on Pg. $11$. We want to show $$\color{blue}{\lim_{r\to\infty} \int \cos^2(rz + t)\, d\pi_{\#}\mu(z) = \frac12} \tag{6.6}$$ for all $t\in \Bbb R$.

Here, $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on the cone $$\mathcal C^d = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_{d+1}): |(x_1, \ldots, x_d)| = |x_{d+1}|\} \subset \Bbb R^{d+1}$$ satisfying $$|\hat\mu(\xi)| \le |\xi|^{-\alpha/2} \quad\quad  \forall \xi\in \Bbb R^{d+1} \tag{6.1}$$
for some $\alpha > d-1$. Further, we assume $\operatorname{supp} \mu \subset \{(\xi, |\xi|) \in \Bbb R^d\times \Bbb R: \epsilon \le |\xi| \le 1/\epsilon\}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\pi:\Bbb R^{d+1} \to \Bbb R$ be the projection map onto the last coordinate; i.e. $\pi: (x_1, \ldots, x_{d+1}) \mapsto x_{d+1}$.

The paper suggests:

> Since $d\ge 2$ and $\alpha/2 > (d-1)/2 \ge 1/2$, $(6.1)$ gives $\pi_{\#}\mu\in L^2(\Bbb R)$. Hence, $\pi_{\#}\mu \in L^1(\Bbb R)$ with $\|\pi_{\#}\mu\|_1 = 1$, and $(6.6)$ then follows by approximating $\pi_{\#}\mu$ in $L^1$ with a finite linear combination
> of characteristic functions of disjoint intervals.

---

- I tried to follow the line of thought in the paper to first show that $\pi_{\#}\mu \in L^2(\Bbb R)$. If we are to use Theorem $3.3$ of Mattila's *Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension*, we shall have to show that $\pi_{\#}\mu\in \mathcal M(\Bbb R)$ and $\widehat{\pi_{\#}\mu}\in L^2(\Bbb R)$. I have \begin{align*}
  \widehat{\pi_{\#}\mu}(\xi) &= \int_{\Bbb R} e^{-2\pi i\xi z} \, d\pi_{\#} \mu(z) \\ &= \int_{\Bbb R^d\times\Bbb R} e^{-2\pi i\xi z}\, d\mu(x,z)\\
  &= \widehat{\mu}(0, \ldots, 0, \xi)
  \end{align*}

So,
$$\int_{\Bbb R} \left| \widehat{\pi_{\#}\mu}(\xi) \right|^2 \, d\xi = \int_{\Bbb R} |\widehat{\mu}(0, \ldots, 0, \xi)|^2\, d\xi \lesssim \int_{\Bbb R} |\xi|^{-\alpha}\, d\xi = 2\int_0^\infty \xi^{-\alpha}\, d\xi$$
Is $\int_0^\infty |\xi|^{-\alpha}\, d\xi < \infty$? Note that $\alpha \ge 1$.

- As suggested by @J.G. in the comments, it's enough to show $$\lim_{r\to\infty} \int e^{2irz}\, d\pi_{\#}\mu(z) = \lim_{r\to\infty}\widehat{\pi_{\#}\mu}\left(-\frac{r}{\pi}\right) = 0$$

---

*Notation.*

- $\mathcal M(\Bbb R^n)$ is the set of all Borel measures $\nu$ satisfying $0 < \nu(\Bbb R^n) < \infty$ with compact support $\operatorname{supp} \nu \subset \Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Hint: let $\Bbb Ef(z):=\int f(z)d\pi_\#\mu(z)$ so$$\Bbb E\cos^{2}(rz+t)=\tfrac12(1+\cos2t\Bbb E\cos(2rz)-\sin2t\Bbb E\sin(2rz)),$$whence your problem reduces to showing $\Bbb E\cos(2rz)=\Bbb E\sin(2rz)=0$, i.e. $\Bbb E\exp(2irz)=0$.

Comment: @J.G. How would you tackle the reduced problem?
$$\mathbb E[e^{2irz}] = \int e^{2irz} \, d\pi_{\#}\mu(z) = \int e^{2irz} \, d\mu(z) \stackrel{?}{=} 0$$

Comment: To prove $e^{2irz}$ averages to $0$, I'd exploit the symmetries of the problem.

Comment: How about showing $\pi_{\#}\mu \in L^1(\Bbb R)$ and using the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma (or similar)? Regardless, could you please give some more details? @J.G.

Comment: @J.G. An answer (possibly detailed) would be great :)

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't know exactly how to make a proof rigorous given the very specific machinery in this problem. I just expect someone who did would do it that way.